# Stacking box-shadows in multiple css selectors

Tags: css

I'm making a little game in Eml, and I'm using css for visualization.
I have a grid with cells, all get the class `cell`.
However there is also one that has the class `selected` with obvious use.

Now, to visualize this to the user I have the following css:

```
.game .cell:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(200, 50, 50, 1);
}
.game .cell.selected {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50, 50, 200, 1);
}
```

So this adds a shadow to the cell you are currently hovering over, and a different one if the cell is selected.
However when you hover over the currently selected one, it just shows the "selected-shadow", not both.

A simple fix of course is to add this:

```
.game .cell.selected:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50, 50, 200, 1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(200, 50, 50, 1);
}
```

Then it works for both, so that's great.
However it's not perfect.
What if I decide to change the hover-effect, then I'll also have to change the selected+hover effect.

So there's duplicated data, and **my question is: can the same be achieved without duplicating data?**

Note: I'm wondering about a pure css solution, no extra libraries such as SASS or similar **if possible**.

Comment: Can you post a simple demo, maybe in jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a little trick and use a pseudo element:

```css
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px; 
  position: relative;
}

.cell:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(200, 50, 50, 1);
}
.cell.selected:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50, 50, 200, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell selected"></div>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks :D